# Post 500 Internal Server Error when using AJAX, Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I think I understand what the error conveys, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I assume it has something to do with the url pattern not being correct. But I've checked and the pattern should be correct. The getSignedRequest method in React calls the ajax function to execute an http post, but an error bounces back saying 500 server error. If anyone could assist in pointing out an error, I'd appreciate it.

**Express - app.js:**

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api/upload', upload)
```

**React - App.js**

```
getSignedRequest(file){
    var fileObject = { file : { type: file.type, size: file.size }}
    console.log("File object to upload: " + JSON.stringify(fileObject));
    jquery.ajax({
        url: "/api/upload/image",
        data: JSON.stringify(fileObject),
        contentType: "applicaiton/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Get data back" + JSON.stringify(data.data))
            this.uploadFile( file, data.data.requestURL, data.data.imageURL );
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err){
            console.log("Error on getting signed request :", err);
        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

**router.js:**

```
router.post('/image', function(req, res, next){


    if( !req.body.file ){ res.json( generalResponse( null, 2 )); return;
    var file = req.body.file;

    if( file.type == "image/png" || file.type == "image/jpeg" || file.type == "image/jpg"){
        if( file.type > 2200000 ){
            res.json( generalResponse( null, 4 )); return;
        }
    }else{
        res.json( generalResponse( null, 4 )); return;
    }

    }
});
```

Comment: share the error stack trace.

Comment: It's something wrong at server, catch and debug exception at server

Comment: I think it because of `/api/upload/image` in AJAX and `/image` in the router. You try to handle different URIs as I understand for one thing. So it may be a mistake.

Comment: The response did occur, I just failed to look at it closely in the nodemon terminal. Thanks Mukesh Sharma